# jQuery event when HTML5 Datalist option is clicked

Tags: html, jquery, html-select, html-datalist

**What I have now:**

So i have this HTML5 Datalist with a bunch of options in it, and I have 2 events firing. One when the user types out something that matches something the array of names that is populating the options such as "Rick Bross" or "Jack Johnson" (keyup). Another event that fires when a user starts typing the name, it pops up, the user arrows down, and hits "enter" (change).

**The problem:**

I need an event to fire when the user clicks one of the drop down options, BEFORE he types the full name out, and before the object is blurred. If a user clicks one right now before the name is completely typed out, the 2 events only fire the function once the input is blurred.

**The Markup:**

```
<datalist id="potentials">
    <option value="Rick Bross">  
    <option value="Jack Johnson">  
    <option value="Rick Bross">  
    <option value="Rick Bross">   
</datalist>
```

**Javascript events and functions:**

```
window.checkModelData = function(ele)
{
    var name = $(ele).val().replace(" ", "");
    var mod = potentialModels[name];
    if(mod) {
        loadModelData(name);
    }
}

function loadModelData(name) {
    var mod = potentialModels[name];
    $("#address").val(potentialModels[name].address);
    $("#city").val(potentialModels[name].city);
    $("#state").val(potentialModels[name].state);
    $("#email").val(potentialModels[name].email);
    $("#phone").val(potentialModels[name].phone);
    $("#zip").val(potentialModels[name].zip);
}

$("#name").keyup(function(){

    window.checkModelData(this);

});
$("#name").change(function(){

    window.checkModelData(this);
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the `input` event instead of the other events. It's actually designed to cover what you want:

```
$("#name").bind('input', function () {
    window.checkModelData(this);
});
```

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AAfuX/) for you to try it out.

Comment: The (input) event is not supported in Edge and IE browsers. What is the alternative for this in Edge browser?

Comment: Be advised: The `input` event ALSO fires whenever the user keys in a character to the input field, delete(s) characters, pastes in text -- not only when one of the `datalist` options is selected. (Tested in Firefox and in Chrome.)

Answer (score -1):

You can also listen to the 'select' event on the input field.

```
$('#name').bind('select', function() {
    // handle input value change
});
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. `input` also fires on every keystroke, `change` only fires on blur.

Comment: In my case, `select`  does not fire at all, only `input` (on every keystroke) and `change` (after pressing Enter or loosing focus). Tested with Chrome, Firefox, using Jquery Mobile.

Comment: Isn't `select` fired when text is selected?

Comment: `select` doesn't fire for me in Chrome, either, whether it's bound to the input element or the list element. Here's a JSFiddle to try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/g8jzn6q5/

Comment: `select` appears to fire on the input if you click & drag to _select_ some text

Answer (score -2):

To handle click only event here is the solution.

```
$("#book_search").bind('select', function () {
    alert("changed");   
});
```