# How do I get the change event for a datalist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-datalist

I am using a datalist and need to detect when the user selects something from the drop-down list. [A similar question has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027746/jquery-event-when-html5-datalist-option-is-clicked) BUT I need it so that the event fires ONLY when the user selects something from the datalist. If they type something in the input then I do NOT want the event to fire. (Notice in the accepted answer to the question I linked that they bind the input, which is not what I want). I've tried (with no success):

```
<datalist>
    <option>Option 1 Here</option> 
    <option>Option 2 Here</option>
</datalist>


$(document).on('change', 'datalist', function(){
   alert('hi');
});
```

EDIT:
This question is different than the suggested question because it's a completely different question.

Comment: I've searched a lot and it seems there isn't any *normal* approaches to do that. You can use `jQuery UI`'s `Autocomplete` widget instead: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: You can use this small script: https://github.com/aFarkas/remote-list. Although it is written to create dynamic datalist for autosuggests, it can also handle static ones. here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/p8LRM/. (docu: https://github.com/aFarkas/remote-list#select-function and demo: http://afarkas.github.io/remote-list/demo/index.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selected value in datalist using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844373/get-selected-value-in-datalist-using-jquery)

Comment: @StephanMuller it's a different question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can manually check it on change. But you need to check change of the input of datalist.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Mbhz4/)

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
  var options = $('datalist')[0].options;
  var val = $(this).val();
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].value === val) {
      console.log(val);
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input list="ff">
<datalist id="ff">
  <option>Option 1 Here</option>
  <option>Option 2 Here</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: There should be a better way to handle this. A datalist may contain entities. If I enter the same name of an existing entity, that doesn't mean the one I typed is the same as the one in the datalist. There may be other fields that differentiate one entity from another other than the name. So choosing an item from the datalist isn't the same as typing the same text in one of the list. This might sound like an edge case for a 6-year-old question, but that's what I'm dealing with right now :)

Answer (score 11):

In browser with the [inputType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/inputType) property on the InputEvent you can use that to filter out any unwanted onInput events. This is "insertReplacementText" on Firefox 81 and null for Chrome/Edge 86. If you need to support IE11 you will need to validate the value is valid.

```js
document.getElementById("browser")
  .addEventListener("input", function(event){
        if(event.inputType == "insertReplacementText" || event.inputType == null) {
          document.getElementById("output").textContent =  event.target.value;
          event.target.value = "";
    }
})
```

```html
<label for="browser">Choose your browser from the list:</label>
<input list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Edge">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

The solutions above all have a big problem. If the datalist has the option of (for example) "bob" and "bobby", as soon as someone types "bob", the code immediately says it's the same as clicking "bob"... but what if they were attempting to type "bobby"?

For a better solution, we need some more information. When listening for the 'input' event on the input field:

In Chromium-based browsers, when you type, delete, backspace, cut, paste, etc. in an input field, the event that is passed to the handler is an `InputEvent`, whereas when you select an option from the datalist, the event is just an `Event` type with a property of `type` that equals 'input'. (This is also true during an auto-fill, at least with BitWarden).

So you can listen for an 'input' event and check to see if it's an instance of `InputEvent` to determine if it's from autofill (which I think should be allowed since most of the time autofill won't be filling these types of fields, and if they do, it's usually a legit choice) / datalist selection.

In Firefox, it's different, though. It still provides an `InputEvent`, but it has an `inputType` property with the value of "insertReplacementText", which we can also use. Autofill does the same thing as Chromium browsers.

So here's a better solution:

```js
$('#yourInput').on('input', function(){
    if (
        !(e instanceof InputEvent) ||
        e.inputType === 'insertReplacementText')
    ) {
        // determine if the value is in the datalist. If so, someone selected a value in the list!
    }
});
```

I wish the browsers had the same implementation that had an event type/property that was exclusive to datalist selection, but they don't so this is the best I've got. I haven't tested this on Safari (I don't have access or time right now) so you should probably take a look at it and see if it's the same or has other distinguishing differences.

---

##### UPDATE:

I noticed that if you already have the full word typed up (e.g. you typed in "Firefox") and then selected the option that matched what you had typed (e.g. you selected the "Firefox" option), it would not fire an "input" event, so you would not know that one of the options was chosen at that point. So, you'll also need a keydown/keypress/keyup event listener to listen to when they press enter. In Chromium browsers, though, it actually provides a key `code` of `undefined` when you hit enter or click on an option (yes, the click makes a keyup event). In Firefox, it says you hit Enter, but it doesn't fire any events I can find when you click an option.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. In both Chrome and Firefox, the `determine if the value is in the datalist` block is executing not only when a value from the datalist is selected, but every time a character is manually typed into the input field. The reason is that in both browsers, `(e instanceof InputEvent)` always evaluates to `false`.

Comment: It's still working just fine for me. `(e instanceof InputEvent)` is evaluating as `true` for me whenever I type, even on mobile, so I don't know why you're seeing something different.

Answer (score 3):

**Optimized Solution**

```
$("input").on('input', function () {
    var inputValue = this.value;
    if($('datalist').find('option').filter(function(){
        return this.value == inputValue;        
    }).length) {
        //your code as per need
        alert(this.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is actually not optimized if the datalist nor options ever change, since every keystroke re-initializes the `$('datalist`)` jQuery object and then instantiates a new array with all the options in this data list, better would be to cache the options "outside" the event handler e.g. have `const myOptions = $('datalist').find('option');` above the `.on` instead of doing it inline in the `if`.

Answer (score 3):

Please have look for your solution it's good to go.
Have look for Demo

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input', function(){
    var optionslist = $('datalist')[0].options;
    var value = $(this).val();
    for (var x=0;x<optionslist.length;x++){
       if (optionslist[x].value === value) {
          //Alert here value
          console.log(value);
          break;
       }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input list="data">
<datalist id="data">
    <option value='1'>Option 1 Here</option> 
    <option value='2'>Option 2 Here</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

**More Optimize**

```
$("input").on('input', function () {
  if($('datalist').find('option[value="'+this.value+'"]')){
    //your code as per need
    alert(this.value);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**This might only be Chrome, untested anywhere else!**, but I see a `change` event triggered when an option is selected. Normally `change` only happens in textfields when the field loses focus. The `change` event triggers before the `blur` event IF it's a normal non-datalist change, so we have to check both: we're looking for a `change` that's not **immediately** followed by a `blur`:

```
var timer;
el.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('datalistchange'));
    }, 1);
});
el.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

And then you can listen for the custom `datalistchange` event like normally. Or you can just put your specific logic instead of the `dispatchEvent`.

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ej3kr26/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery('input').on('input', function () {
  if($('datalist[id="' + jQuery(this).attr('list') + '"]').find('option[value="'+this.value+'"]')){
    //your code as per need
    alert(this.value);
  }
});
```

so it will find the datalist associated with the input

Answer (score 0):

8 years, and still no good answer

Simple space-suffix trick will do what you need, add &nbsp; at the end of each option, and then detect (and remove) it in "input" handler

```
<input list="my-options" id="my-input">
<datalist id="my-options">
  <option>Option 1 Here&nbsp;</option>
  <option>Option 2 Here&nbsp;</option>
</datalist>

<script>
$('#my-input').on('input',function (e)
{
        var v=$(e.target).val();
        if (v.slice(-1)=='\xa0')
        {
                $(e.target).val(v=v.slice(0,-1));
                console.log("option selected '"+v+"'");
        };
});
 
</script>
```

Comment: what were w3 guys thinking